# Hadoop v2.7 pseudo distributed installation NativeCodeLoader error

Tags: installation, hadoop2

I've tried to install hadoop in my system and first i was getting permissions that i was able to resolve by just a simple chmod and chown but after solving this issue now there is a new error that arises whenever I use `start-dfs.sh`

```
kishan@RoCk ~ $ start-dfs.sh
17/04/08 12:22:18 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-kishan-namenode-RoCk.out 
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-kishan-datanode-RoCk.out 
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-kishan-secondarynamenode-RoCk.out 
17/04/08 12:22:33 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
kishan@RoCk ~ $ jps
10303 Jps
```

it's a warning but all the nodes are not running.

**UPDATE:**
Namenode `ERROR` log:

```
2017-04-09 21:32:40,002 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/kishan/hdfs/namenode is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:812)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:796)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1559)
2017-04-09 21:32:40,003 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Comment: Looks like you have not configured the installation yet.

Comment: Are you able to see all the nodes on a cluster manager ,if yes then can you give a bit more information on failures associated with Node startups or if you are able to access log files on the platform .

Comment: @Kfactor21 can you tell me which logs or which config files should i upload ?

Comment: @franklinsijo i am pretty new at this thing so if you can tell me in detail, it'll be more helpfull

Comment: Follow the configuration part in this [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/hadoop/926/getting-started-with-hadoop/3061/installation-or-setup-on-linux#t=201704091425013180117)

Comment: @franklinsijo i've completed every step in the documentation but the start-dfs.sh is not able to run the namenode, datanode & the secondary node and gives the following errors when i give the start-dfs.sh   WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.

Comment: Can you post your `hdfs-site.xml` and `core-site.xml`?

Comment: @franklinsijo hdfs-site.xml   <configuration>
     <property>
         <name>dfs.replication</name>
         <value>1</value>
     </property>
     <property>
         <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
         <value>file:///home/kishan/hdfs/namenode</value>
     </property>
     <property>
         <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name> 
         <value>file:///home/kishan/hdfs/datanode</value> 
     </property>
 </configuration>

Comment: core-site.xml     <configuration>
 <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS </name>
      <value> hdfs://localhost:8020 </value> 
   </property>
</configuration>

Comment: You must edit the question to include these information and not add it in comments. Did you format the namenode?

Comment: @franklinsijo oh yeah i replaced it and now i am able to run the secondarynode but i have had no luck starting the namenode and the datanode

Comment: Check the log file of namenode `/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-kishan-namenode-RoCk.log` for `ERROR` and post the error. Please add the error to the post by clicking on the edit option. Do not add them here in comments.

Comment: formated the namenode twice just to be sure and i am new to stackoverflow as well so i am not familiar with the way of asking questions here but it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/kishan/hdfs/namenode is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible
```

Your `Namenode` needs a format.

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

If the `Datanode` data directories were already created, manually remove them before re-starting the cluster.

Comment: actually i had to change the permissions for the Datanode directory

Comment: That would answer why your datanode did not start!